# How to split the line features where point intersects without having intersection vertex in qgis

Tags: pyqgis

I have a polyline and a point layer. I want to split the line where point is intersecting with the line but sometimes vertex wont be present where point is intersecting.

```
def splitting():
    selectedFeatures = []
    for l_feat in l_layer.getFeatures():
        l_geom = l_feat.geometry().asPolyline()
        l_featid = l_feat.id()
        print('l_geom is',l_geom)
        g_layer.select(l_featid)
        sel_feat = g_layer.selectedFeatures()[0]
        sel_feat_geom = sel_feat.geometry()
        for p_feat in p_layer.getFeatures():
            if p_feat.geometry().intersects(sel_feat_geom):
                intersection_geom = p_feat.geometry().intersection(sel_feat_geom)
                if intersection_geom.asPoint() != l_geom[0] and intersection_geom.asPoint() !=l_geom[-1]:
                    print '------', p_feat.id()
                    l_layer.startEditing()
#                    l_layer.select(l_feat.id())
                    t = l_layer.splitFeatures([intersection_geom.asPoint()],True)
                    print('t is',t)
                    l_layer.commitChanges()
#                    l_layer.removeSelection()
                else:
                    pass
            g_layer.removeSelection()
    qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
```

Here `t = l_layer.splitFeatures([intersection_geom.asPoint()],True)` is writing 0 but it is not spliting line.What is going wrong here.How to do it in QGIS

Comment: https://issues.qgis.org/issues/16841  The suggested workaround is to add a vertex first, then do the split

Comment: @JGH But how to insert a vertex where point feature lies on the polyline.

Comment: You don't have success because 'splitFeatures' method of **QgsVectorLayer** uses a **QgsPoint** list of a cut line; not a list of a single point. Please, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have success because 'splitFeatures' method of **QgsVectorLayer** uses a **QgsPoint** list of a [cut line](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#a3eda422df6dea6c7830af91f11aea3ec); not a list of a single point. On the other hand, your code looks complicated. It could be simpler. For instance, at situation of following image, it can be observed one feature at attributes table of **new_line** layer:

[image]

Following code uses **cut_line** layer, in Editing Mode, to cut **new_line** at visualized point (above image):

```
registry = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance()

line = registry.mapLayersByName("new_line")
cut_line = registry.mapLayersByName("cut_line")

l_feat = cut_line[0].getFeatures().next()

l_cut = l_feat.geometry().asPolyline()

print line[0].splitFeatures(l_cut, True)
```

After running above code, it can be observed that it was effectively created a new feature (selected at following image) as expected. It works in this way.

[image]